# XAML Path - Draw a Circle without using Arcs

Tags: wpf, xaml

In a WPF application, I understand I can draw a Circle using the following Path Syntax:

```
<Path
    Stretch="Fill"
    StrokeThickness="1"
    Data="M -1,0 A 1,1 0 1 1 1,0 M -1,0 A 1,1 0 1 0 1,0" />
```

However, I am working in a compiler that does not yet support Arcs ([C# & XAML for HTML5](http://www.cshtml5.com/)).

How would I draw this circle without using Arcs?
Is the solution to draw a point-by-point item - essentially a Hexagon, give or take?

Comment: How about drawing an `Ellipse` instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want to draw a circle you can draw Ellpise as @lokusking  mentioned in comments. You can make it like this.

```
 <Ellipse Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="1" Fill="Black"></Ellipse>
```

If you want to draw somthing more complicated, please use canvas and draw figure line by line. Here is example for hexagon.

```
<Viewbox Width="200" Height="200">
      <Canvas Width="400" Height="400">
         <Line
            Stroke="Black"
            StrokeThickness="2"
            X1="0"
            X2="200"
            Y1="100"
            Y2="0"/>
         <Line
            Stroke="Black"
            StrokeThickness="2"
            X1="200"
            X2="400"
            Y1="0"
            Y2="100"/>
         <Line
            Stroke="Black"
            StrokeThickness="2"
            X1="400"
            X2="400"
            Y1="100"
            Y2="300"/>
         <Line
            Stroke="Black"
            StrokeThickness="2"
            X1="400"
            X2="200"
            Y1="300"
            Y2="400"/>
         <Line
            Stroke="Black"
            StrokeThickness="2"
            X1="200"
            X2="0"
            Y1="400"
            Y2="300"/>
         <Line
            Stroke="Black"
            StrokeThickness="2"
            X1="0"
            X2="0"
            Y1="300"
            Y2="100"/>
      </Canvas>
   </Viewbox>
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 7):

Better than drawing an `Ellipse` element would be to use a `EllipseGeometry`.

Instead of being top/left aligned, your drawing is centered at specific coordinates. In addition, the `StrokeThickness` contributes to the total width and height of an Ellipse, while a Geometry exactly defines the rendered shape.

```
<Path Stretch="Fill" StrokeThickness="1">
    <Path.Data>
        <EllipseGeometry Center="0,0" RadiusX="1" RadiusY="1"/>
    </Path.Data>
</Path>
```